# Whitelist in php

Tags: php, user-input, whitelist

I have an input for users where they are supposed to enter their phone number. The problem is that some people write their phone number with hyphens and spaces in them. I want to put the input trough a filter to remove such things and store only digits in my database.

I figured that I could do some str_replace() for the whitespaces and special chars.
However I think that a better approach would be to pick out just the digits instead of removing everything else. I think that I have heard the term "whitelisting" about this.

Could you please point me in the direction of solving this in PHP?

**Example**: I want the input "0333 452-123-4" to result in "03334521234"

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a non-trivial problem because there are lots of colloquialisms and regional differences. Please refer to [What is the best way for converting phone numbers into international format (E.164) using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187216/what-is-the-best-way-for-converting-phone-numbers-into-international-format-e-16) It's Java but the same rules apply.

I would say that unless you need something more fully-featured, keep it simple. Create a list of valid regular expressions and check the input against each until you find a match.

If you want it *really* simple, simply remove non-digits:

```
$phone = preg_replace('![^\d]+!', '', $phone);
```

By the way, just picking out the digits is, by definition, the same as removing everything else. If you mean something different you may want to rephrase that.

Comment: Your example code did work very well but I had a real hard time trying to understand it. I wrote:
$phone = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $phone);
instead. Is there a difference between these two? Where can I read more about the exclamation marks you use?

Comment: The only difference is that I'm replacing a group of non-digits with an empty string (hence the + operator to indicate one or more) rather than a single non-digit with an empty string. Very minor difference really.

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = filter_var(str_replace(array("+","-"), '', $number), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

`Filter_Var` removes everything but pluses and minuses, and str_replace gets rid of those.

or you could use preg_replace

```
$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it two ways. Iterate through each index in the string, and run is_numeric() on it, or you could use a regular expression on the string.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side I do recommand using some formating that you design when creating a form. This is good for zip or telephone fields. Take a look at this jquery [plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for a reference. It will much easy later on the server side.