# How can we format a telephone number using Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Can anyone let me know how can I format a telephone number automatically using javascript.
I have seen some of the code samples in the internet....But my point is not all the countries have the country code just 3 numbers.....and moreover if someone write the country code 0091 and the number will be like 9878...... Then the codes I have seen in the internet formats them like (009)-(19878...) . If u see the country code will be taken wrong ......

Can someone clear out this

Thanks

Comment: Please show some real-world examples - this is not exactly trivial. What about numbers like `+911234567890` for example? Do you need to parse those too? Because for that, you would need a list of country codes to find out whether the country code part is `+9`, `+91`, or `+911`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way for converting phone numbers into international format (E.164) using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187216/what-is-the-best-way-for-converting-phone-numbers-into-international-format-e-16)

Comment: Although that other question says Java, all the answers are generic (and say "it's hard")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look at libphonenumber:

http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/